# Viewing the internal files through folder picker in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro through which I can select a folder by double clicking. The path of this folder is later used to open some files (in the folder).

The code for the macro to select the folder is:

```
Sub GetFolder()

    Dim folderselected As String

    Set myFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With myFolder

        .Title = "Choose Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False

        If .Show <> -1 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        folderselected = .SelectedItems(1)

    End With

    DataPath = folderselected & "\"

End Sub
```

Now when I click the folder, the explorer interface shows ."No items match your search", although there are files in the folder.

Is there a way to extend this code, where I can select the folder, retrieve the datapath and also get to view the files in the explorer display (but of course not select it) ??

Comment: consider using `msoFileDialogFilePicker` instead of `msoFileDialogFolderPicker`. You will be able to both find correct folder and you will see and be able to select files as well.

Comment: Thank you. But thats the thing. I dont want to select files, I just want to view them and retrieve their path. However, I want to view the filles in the folder, when I select the folder

Comment: How about you craft a form which does exactly what you want? The `ListView` might be of help with that. Then you could design a form containing two ListViews. One to navigate the folders and another one to show the files within.